# Ionic Keyboard close not fired

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, keyboard

I'm trying to close the keyboard when the user do scroll on the app. This is the code:

.html

```
<ion-content class="maincontent" (ionScrollStart)="scrollStart()">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

.ts

```
scrollStart() {
  Keyboard.close();
}
```

The event `ionScrollStart` is working fine, and I have added the correct dependencies to make the Keyboard works. Any ideas?

Comment: should not it be `this.keyboard.close();` ?

Comment: If I declare a property keyboard and try to access the close function, it returns me "Property 'close' does not exist on type 'Keyboard'", so I have to use it directly as Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

install plugins

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

add in `app.module.ts`

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Keyboard
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
```

using in ts:

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

scrollStart() {
   this.keyboard.close();
}
```

See it [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/)

Comment: That's the way I'm doint it, but it doesn't work, moreover all properties of keyboard are statics, so I don't need to instance a keyboard property, so I use Keyboard.close() or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard plugin dosnt work in ionic (at least free version).

to get keyboard open/close event do like this:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
public IsKeyboardOpen:boolean=false;
    constructor(public ngZ:NgZone)
    {
        var innerHeight=window.innerHeight;
        window.onresize = (e) =>
       {
        this.ngZ.run(() => 
        {
          if(window.innerHeight< innerHeight)
          {
            this.IsKeyboardOpen=true;
          }
          else
          {
            this.IsKeyboardOpen=false;
          }
        });
    };
    }
```

to close soft keyboard, focus to any other element that is not input, like this:

```
func()
{
   this.myButton.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: In fact, the events `Keyboard.onKeyboardShow()` and `Keyboard.onKeyboardHide()` are working fine, It's only the Keyboard.close() which is not working

Answer (score 0):

Include `public keyboard: Keyboard` in your page `constructor`.  Then you can call `this.keyboard.close();`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,the explanation I can think of is that keyboard.close() event has now been changed to keyboard.hide()